# Why is Sonic so fast?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

As we all know, [**Sonic the Hedgehog**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_(character)) is the main protagonist of the Sega [game series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog).

[image: Sonic the Hedgehog]
<sup>[img src](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/shipping/images/9/9c/Sonic_the_Hedgehog.png/revision/latest?cb=20160524143736)</sup>

What I've always wondered is, **what makes Sonic so fast?**

Obviously the out-of-universe answer is that his games are 'speed based' where the player needs to react fast in order to do well, but I'm looking for an in-universe answer.

I know that in some iterations there's mention of his shoes making him fast, and according to other sources, it's just because he inherently *is* fast, that's all:

> [Sonic] has the ability to run at supersonic speeds and the ability to curl into a ball
> <sub>-Wikipedia, [Sonic the Hedgehog (Character)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_(character))</sub>

In fact, in many of the iterations of the game, there are 'power ups' which grant Sonic even greater speed, but I've not seen anything official about the origins of this speed. Is there any official explanation given for Sonic's speed?

---

<sup>Note: I don't necessary care about [how fast he can run](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18685/21267), rather *why* he is so fast to begin with.</sup>

Comment: This reddit thread is pretty interesting. https://www.reddit.com/r/gamegrumps/comments/15lmrf/real_talk_why_is_sonic_is_so_gosh_darn_fast/

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133564/is-the-world-sonic-lives-in-technologically-advanced

Comment: Some out-of-universe backstory here; http://info.sonicretro.org/Original_Story

Comment: “[Sonic] has the ability to run at supersonic speeds and the ability to curl into a ball” — I’m not convinced the second one counts as a noteworthy ability. I mean, I can curl into a ball.

Comment: @Paul I always *knew* you were Sonic!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Can you curl up into a perfectly round ball?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite More importantly, turning into a ball [is just what hedgehogs _do_ anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ21hh-MKlo)

Comment: @Doval: can *Sonic?* “Perfectly” round is quite an ambitious target, especially with 16-bit graphics.

Comment: @Paul He's always been rendered as close to a perfect sphere as the hardware will allow. More importantly, rolling down slopes allows him to exceed his running speed. He's not the only character in the franchise that can do that, but there are characters that can't.

Comment: @Doval: so he runs so slowly that he needs to curl up into a ball to speed him? This is yet more evidence that that cursed hedgehog is no better than me.

Comment: This is gold. haha.

Comment: Curling into a ball is not a special ability for a hedgehog.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Sonic's (in-universe) background is seen in a special comic edition called "[The Origin of Sonic](http://stc.wikia.com/wiki/The_Origin_of_Sonic)"

In short, Sonic was already *pretty fast* (for a hedgehog) when he first encountered Dr Robotnik.

> "*The fastest hedgehog on the planet*"

[image]

Robotnik provided him with "*power sneakers*" and allowed him to train on his *"kinetic gyratoscope"*, resulting in Sonic being able to run at super-sonic speed.

[image]

---

The comic itself is a retelling of an earlier work; The licensed book [Stay Sonic](http://info.sonicretro.org/Stay_Sonic#Sonic_the_Hedgehog)

> Partly out of curiosity, and partly to assist Dr K in his research,
>   Sonic put in several hours a day on a solar-powered treadmill that the
>   Doc had built for him. The treadmill, or Kinetic Gyratosphere™ to give
>   it its patented name, was capable of revolving at high speeds. Sonic
>   protested that it made him feel like a gerbil on steroids. However,
>   when Kintobor developed special friction-reducing trainers for him he
>   became more interested. The cutting edge design and classic red
>   styling hid some state of the art additions including Duratex™ soles
>   with exceptional grip and specially cushioned odourless inners.
>   Covering as much ground at the speeds he did frequently left him with
>   blistered feel. They were also a necessary safety measure because
>   Sonic started to build up the sort of static that could ignite the
>   treadmill or shoot sparks into the lab. Gradually Sonic increased his
>   speed to 200, 400, then 500 mph.
>
> Kintobor torqued up the treadmill every day, pushing it in
>   20-mile-on-hour increments What hod begun as an idle exercise was
>   developing into a majorly phenomenal experiment Then one day,
>   impossibly. Sonic crossed all known limits of mammalian acceleration
>   and broke the sound barrier The treadmill had been running for
>   thirty-five minutes and he was little more than a blur when suddenly
>   there was an enormous bang and a tremendous wind swept all the papers
>   into the air. Alarmed, Kintobor attempted to slow down the treadmill -
>   stopping it dead would have had disastrous consequences, probably
>   sending Sonic into orbit over Mobius. Eventually he managed to gain
>   control of the machine and gradually reduce Sonic's velocity, but it
>   took nearly an hour to bring it to a stop
>
> When, finally, Sonic stepped breathlessly out of the treadmill he
>   wasn't the same hedgehog that had gone in. His physical appearance had
>   changed dramatically. Instead of his unexceptional, greyish-brown
>   shade., most of Sonic's body had turned brilliant, cobalt blue, on his
>   spikes stood straight back in a stiff mohawk
>
> My word!' exclaimed Kintobor, struggling to comprehend what had just
>   happened I think you've gone blue from the shock waves Not to mention
>   the Cobalt Effect™' he said
>
> You clocked up 761 miles per hour! You've really earned your name now!
>   In fact, I should call you SuperSonic - what do you think of that?'
>   Kintobor cried, dancing around the lab like a demented, er, scientist.
>
> SuperSonic, yeah - radical Cool.' grinned Sonic, examining his glowing
>   blue body proudly in a mirror, but what about getting some food? All
>   that running's made me hungry!'

And which in turn is a version of an even earlier backstory given for Sonic in the original "[SEGA Sonic bible](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_Bible)"

> Still, he knew he'd never be a nerd like Dr. K. So partly for
>   relaxation, and partly for Dr. K's amusement, he logged in several
>   hours a day on the supersonic treadmill that Kintobor had -built for
>   him. Slowly, Sonny built his speed to 200 , 400, then 761 m.p.h. --
>   the speed of sound. Then, impossibly, he crossed all known limits of
>   acceleration and began running at the speed of light. Alarmed,
>   Kintobor tried to slow the treadmill. Although he managed to gain
>   control of the machine and bring his friend's velocity down slowly, a
>   change had come over Sonny. Instead of his unexceptional,
>   grayish-brown color, most of his body had turned cobalt blue, and his
>   quills stood straight back in a stiff mohawk.
>
> "My word!" exclaimed Kintobor, who struggled to comprehend what had
>   just happened. "1 think you've gone blue from the Advanced Non-
>   Concussive Cobalt Effect!" he said, helping Sonny from the treadmill.
>
> " 186 thousand miles per second! You're so fast, we should call you
>   Sonic. SuperSonic, even. How do like that!" he cried, dancing around
>   the lab like a demented pixie.

Comment: 186,000 miles per second? Sonic can move at the speed of light?

Comment: If Sonic broke the speed of sound by running at 761 mph, then assuming that was was running through air, the temperature must have been below zero degrees Celsius (the speed of sound at room temperature is a little higher, around 767 mph). Perhaps that makes sense, as Sonic was presumably generating a lot of internal heat by running so fast, and would need to be cooled down. But it still sounds pretty uncomfortable.

Comment: Disappointing that they felt the need to create a reason for him to be fast... Can't he just be a cartoon character? (Yes I know it's a game, but in the style of a cartoon) I mean, we don't ask why Bugs Bunny can talk or how Mickey Mouse turned into a weird humanoid mutant with big round ears.

Comment: If i read this correctly, it doesn't really explain why he can run so fast. All the doctor did was provide him with shoes that can stand his speed (friction-reducing shoes with exceptional grip (???)), and let him train.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I'm also not sure how he could break the speed of sound (to create a sonic boom) while running on a treadmill.

Comment: @phresnel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zQ-Rs8HwOk

Comment: @Sparhawk - His feet would be moving supersonic speeds.

Comment: @Valorum I did consider that interpretation, but he does say "I broke the speed of sound". I think it's a pretty loose interpretation to have it refer to his feet. In any case, the parts of the circular treadmill on the outside would move even more quickly than his feet, and hit the speed of sound first, but there's no mention of that. Finally… I think we're overthinking it, and there's the slight possibility that it's just poorly written!

Comment: The most fascinating part of this story to me is that Dr. Robotnik used to be good-hearted and that he and Sonic used to be on good terms. What happened to change that?

Comment: @Kevin - His lab blew up and he was infected with evil Emerald power

Comment: In case anyone hasn't noticed, these stories are rehashes of several origin stories of _The Flash_. Or let's be friendly and say, parodies.

Comment: This answer is only canon for the comic universe from which it comes. In the Sonic games, Eggman has no such prior history of being kind and experimenting on Sonic the Ugly Brown Hedgehog.

Comment: "Friction reduced trainers!" Wouldn't that make him slower? The more friction you have on your shoes, the faster you can run. For the same reason tires are made out of rubber. But interestingly, on a treadmill, less friction is indeed better. Because you can just stay in place and be in the air as long as possible while the treadmill moves under you. So in this scene, the explanation of the shoes would actually make sense, it just doesn't apply to running forwards.

Comment: @Valorum So Sonic's intention is to remove the evil Emerald power from Dr. Robotnik's body?

Answer (score 19):

In most continuities I can think of, including the current game canon, no explanation is ever given for Sonic's super-speed. He just naturally *is* that fast. In *Sonic Underground* he's shown to be unnaturally fast even as a toddler (though admittedly, *Underground* isn't exactly the most accurate Sonic adaptation). It should be noted that the backstory given in "The Origin of Sonic", as posted by Valorum:

a) Only applied in the West (SEGA of Japan used a different backstory because the two regional branches of SEGA didn't see eye-to-eye back then)
b) Ceased to be canon, to the best of my knowledge, when the two regional continuities were combined starting with *Sonic Adventure*.

The only other continuity I know of in which Sonic's speed is explained to some extent is the cartoon *Adventures of Sonic the Hedgehog*. In the episode "The Mystery of the Missing Hi-tops", Sonic's distinctive red sneakers are stolen and he is left unable to run, as without them, his feet burn up. But even there, Sonic's speed is apparently all-natural, he just can't utilize it properly without the shoes.

Comment: The idea that there's a consistent Sonic 'canon' is somewhat amusing. I think we've all been spoiled by Star Wars

Comment: @Valorum - I'm suddenly thinking of the old Ferrero Roche (sp?) advert at the diplomatic reception.  Only this time the line is: "Ah, M. Lucas, with this canon you're really spoiling us..."

Comment: @Valorum Consistent?? Star Wars?? Man, Star Wars is Retcon Central! I mean, hey, what's that whooshing sound?

Comment: As I said with Valorum's answer … If you're wondering how he got so fast, and other science facts, then repeat to yourself:  ‘It's just a game, I should really just relax.’

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we go by the Archie Sonic comics story line (which is not canon), Shadow, Silver and some other characters have their special abilities due to the Chaos Force, so I assume it applies to Sonic as well.

Comment: You may be overthinking the scope of "canon" when it applies to a property with practically no story control, with a licence held by a dozen companies.

Comment: @Valorum Most fans consider the "canon" of video games to be a real and knowable thing, based on the appearance of the "same" character between multiple games, and excluding things which we are explicitly told are spin-off universes/alternate timelines/retconned. Cartoons/movies, comics/manga, etc. are usually discounted unless referenced by the games themselves. The "same character" clause discounts things like the Sonic comics, for example -- Sonic in the games lives on Earth, Sonic in the comics lives on Mobius.

Comment: @ArrowCase - Per my comment above, the idea that the games (or comics or manuals or whatever) form a consistent canon narrative for a video-game character like Sonic is frankly ridiculous given the sheer diversity of back-stories and retcons that he's gone through.

Comment: @Valorum I don't think there's anything ridiculous about considering a pretty simple continuity of game plots to be a "canon" when strung together. Sonic doesn't have multiple origins in his games; he doesn't have really any origins at all. We'll have to agree to disagree (or get moved to chat).

Answer (score -2):

Sonic is fast because of multiple reasons, it just depends on if you're talking about the shows, games, or comics.

With the comics it is because of his genes. It basically runs in his DNA and most of the other hedgehogs' DNA. Hedgehogs in the comics naturally have some speed, they just have to work to develop it.

Now if you're talking about the shows, yes he is still born with it, but it most likely does not run in the family (he was the first one with speed in his family to be a speedster).

And finally if you're talking about the games, he gets it from the Chaos Force, because the games most likely followed the elements of the comics. It was because his father was a chaos user and it might have transferred into speed for the Chaos Force ability he would have had.

So basically, no, the shoes are not what makes him fast, they just help with the fact that he is so fast.

Comment: "The games most likely followed the comics"? But the games came first... and Sonic's father has never appeared in the games.

Comment: @raisinghellyer - Excellent work fixing this.